# I need help with a SQL query. Fetching an entry, it's most recent revision and it's fields

Tags: sql, join

I'm building a CMS for my own needs, and finished planning my database layout.

Basically I am abstracting all possible data-models into "sections" and all entries into one table. The final layout is as follows:

**Database diagram:** [I have yet to be allowed to post images, so here is a link to a diagram of my database](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e8f2cbd9bf.png).

Entries (**section_entries**) are children of their section (**sections**). I save all edits to the entries in a new revision (**section_entries_revisions**), and also track revisions on the sections (**section_revisions**), in order to match the values of a revision, to the fields of the section that existed when the entry-revision was made. The section-revisions can have a number of fields (**section_revision_fields**) that define the attributes of entries in the section. There is a many-to-many relationship between the fields (**section_revision_fields**) and the entry-revisions (**section_entry_revisions**), that stores the values of the attributes defined by the section revision.

The key-icons on the database-diagram indicate what columns are part of the primary key. Most of the tables have identifying relationships.

Feel free to ask questions if the diagram is confusing.

Now, this is the most complex SQL I've ever worked with, and the task of fetching my data is a little daunting.

Basically what i want help with, is fetching an entry, when the only known variables are; **section_id, section_entry_id**. The query should fetch the most recent revision of that entry (most recent, being the revision with the highest **id**), and the section_revision model corresponding to **section_revision_id** in the **section_entry_revisions** table. It should also fetch the values of the fields in the section-revision.

I was hoping for a query result, where there would be as many rows as fields in the section. Each row would contain the information of the entry and the section, and then information for one of the fields (e.g. each row corresponding to a field and it's value).

I tried to explain the best I could. Again, feel free to ask questions if my description somehow lacking.

I hope someone is up for the challenge. Best regards. :-)

## The Query So Far

```
SELECT ser.*, sersrf.value

FROM section_entry_revisions AS ser

JOIN section_entry_revisions_section_revision_fields AS sersrf
  ON sersrf.section_entry_revision_id = ser.id

WHERE ser.section_id = 1
  AND ser.section_entry_id = 1
  AND ser.id = (

    SELECT MAX(subser.id)

    FROM section_entry_revisions AS subser

    WHERE subser.section_id = ser.section_id
      AND subser.section_entry_id = ser.section_entry_id

  )
```

Now I want to join the field values, with the field names from the particular section_revision.

Comment: What is missing from using `SELECT se.* FROM SECTION_ENTRIES se WHERE se.section_id = @section_id AND se.id = @section_entry_id`?

Comment: That returns only the particular **section_entries** element. What I need to figure out, are the joins required to achieve the result described above. The query you provided is quite possibly the basis of the query I need, but I believe we will need several joins (and perhaps subqueries for getting the latest revision ids) in order to fetch the rest of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the real trick is finding the last revision. You did not specify how "last" is determined so I assumed it was based on `created`. Your diagram also did not specify primary keys so I assumed that the PK of `section_entry_revisions` was `Id`.

```
Select ...
From section_entry_revisions As SER
    Join section_entry_revisions_section_revision_fields As SRF
        On SRF.section_revision_id = SER.Id
    ...
Where SER.sectionId = @SectionId
    And SER.section_entry_id = @SectionEntryId
    And SER.id =    (
                    Select Max(SER1.id)
                    From section_entry_revisions As SER1
                    Where SER1.section_Id = SER.section_Id
                        And SER1.section_entry_id = SER.section_entry_id 
                    Group By SER1.sectionId, SER1.section_entry_id
                    Having SER.created= Max(SER1.created)
                    )
```

**ADDITION**

If "last" is solely determined by `section_entry_revisions.id`, then you can eliminate the Having and Group By clause I used in the subquery in my original example.

If the key icon represents the primary key, then that means that `section_id`, `section_entry_id` and `id` all makeup the primary key? Is Id in that table an identity column? If so, why isn't it the lone primary key and the other two part of a candidate key (unique constraint)?

To get to the `section_revision_fields` values, you should be able to join directly to the `section_revision_fields` table. All that the subquery has done is filter the `section_entry_revisions` rows down to a single row. Now that you have that, you can follow the relationships to get the data from the related tables using standard joins unless there is an additional problem to be solved here. Here is the revised query:

```
Select ...
From section_entry_revisions As SER
    Join section_revision_fields As SRF
        On SRF.section_id = SER.section_id
            And SRF.section_revision_id = SER.section_revision_id
    ...
Where SER.sectionId = @SectionId
    And SER.section_entry_id = @SectionEntryId
    And SER.id =    (
                    Select Max(SER1.id)
                    From section_entry_revisions As SER1
                    Where SER1.section_Id = SER.section_Id
                        And SER1.section_entry_id = SER.section_entry_id 
                    )
```

Comment: "last" is determined by section_entry_revisions.id. And most of the tables have identifying relationships; the small key-icons on the database diagram indicate that the column is part of the primary key. I'll update my post accordingly. :-)

And yes, a subquery must be the best way of getting the latest revision id. Now, how would I go on about joining the section_revision tables and fetch the field names and values?

Comment: I am also wondering, if it is possible to use a subquery in case I want to fetch multiple entries, but only their latest revision. The subquery is only usable if the query is for one specific entry. Maybe using GROUP BY somehow?

Comment: @Tigger ate my dad- Use the subquery to filter down the `section_entry_revisions` to a single revision. If you want to retrieve data from that table in the SELECT clause, put `section_entry_revisions` in the FROM clause as I did in my example.

Comment: The subquery in your FROM clause returns a single value, but when fetching a number of sections their particular revision_id's will differ. I think a exclusion join is the way to go; `LEFT JOIN section_revisions AS sr_exclude ON sr_exclude.section_id = sr.section_id AND sr_exclude.id > sr.id WHERE sr_exclude.section_id IS NULL`. This will limit the result to the latest revisions and I wont have to do a subquery for each section.

Comment: @Zackman - That will also work. Either way, once you have filter down to the one revision you want, you can then add joins to get the columns you want.